# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in json

Tags: json

I have read online that the unexpected token issue can come from using `JSON.parse()`.

I am getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`

What I am doing wrong?

My code look like this

```
var t=null;
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(responseText)
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 &&xmlhttp.status==200)
    var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var str=JSON.stringify(obj);
    var newArr = JSON.parse(str);
    var len=newArr.length;
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change","sales_home.html");
    $(document).on('pageshow', "#temp", function (event, data) {
        while (len > 0) {

          len--;
        }
    });
}
xmlhttp.onerror=function(E)
{
    alert("error"+ E);
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","url",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem becomes apparent if you indent the code consistently and correctly:

```
var t = null;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(responseText) {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var str = JSON.stringify(obj);                       // <====
    var newArr = JSON.parse(str);                        // <====
    var len = newArr.length;
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "sales_home.html");
    $(document).on('pageshow', "#temp", function(event, data) {
        while (len > 0) {

            len--;
        }
    });
}
xmlhttp.onerror = function(E) {
    alert("error" + E);
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "url", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Note how the code does

```
var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
var newArr = JSON.parse(str);
```

*no matter what the value of `readyState` and `status` are*. That causes the error, because `obj` will be `undefined`, so `JSON.stringify(obj)` will return `undefined`, so `JSON.parse` will coerce that to the string `"undefined"`, which it then cannot parse, failing on the first character, `u`.

You probably want to add a block:

```
var t = null;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(responseText) {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { // Block starts here
        var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
        var newArr = JSON.parse(str);
        var len = newArr.length;
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "sales_home.html");
        $(document).on('pageshow', "#temp", function(event, data) {
            while (len > 0) {

                len--;
            }
        });
    }                                                       // Block ends here
}
xmlhttp.onerror = function(E) {
    alert("error" + E);
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "url", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

---

Not quite following why you're parsing, then stringifying, then parsing again though... Or why you have an empty `while` loop...